# Compress jpeg images from Terminal

Tags: terminal, image-editing, compression

I am looking for a way to compress jpeg images on a Mac from Terminal. Basically, a library like pngquant, except it is for jpeg format.

Are you aware of a software that does that?

Comment: The question reads as if you are looking to losslessly compress a jpg file - which of course cannot be done. All you can do is make it smaller by making it lossier.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) which is a newer and more efficient image processing system than [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php). Both apps are available via direct [download](https://sourceforge.net/projects/graphicsmagick/files/graphicsmagick-binaries/), [MacPorts](https://ports.macports.org/port/GraphicsMagick/), and [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/graphicsmagick).

I suggest using GraphicsMagick as it is smaller and faster than ImageMagic. The commands are generally the same with the only difference being that you prepend a `gm` with the GraphicsMagick tool.  `gm` is the binary with the commands `convert`, `identify`, `mogrify`, etc. are arguments where as IM, the same arguments are individual binaries.

The commands are as follows:

- GraphicsMagick:

  `gm convert -quality X% source.jpg result.jpg`
- ImageMagick:

  `convert -quality X% source.jpg result.jpg`

`X` is a positive integer value (i.e. 85 for 85%); source and result are the original filename and the output filename.

Comment: I think the command is actually "convert", not "compress".

Comment: I confirmed that it should be "convert" in 2022

Comment: @HangChen…I’ve updated with correct command and a better tool