# Command-line to use Remove Background action of MacOS Ventura

Tags: finder, command-line, automator, graphics

I want to use the quick action: Remove Background, which is available in the Finder of MacOS Ventura (right click -> quick actions -> Remove Background)

Does someone know how to do it with a Terminal command-line / shell script?

I tried to record the action in Automator, but without any luck. It ends up with a Watch Me Do action which I can't do anything with. But maybe i'm doing something wrong and there is another way.
With the action I don't want the Finder to come up front. So on a way that the app with the shell function keeps upfront. I'm using Max from cycling'74 for the shell commands.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a `shortcuts` command and an `automator` command that you can use to trigger Shortcuts and Automator workflows.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never used Shortcuts, but i made a shortcut which removes the background and with shortcut command-line it's perfect.

Comment: @Aart could you share your Shortcut? can you batch remove backgrounds? `shortcuts run "Remove Background" -i /path/to/folder/*.jpg` [?]

Comment: You can start by using `screencapture -iW ~/Desktop/screenshot.png`. This will capture a screenshot without the background. You can then use `open -a "Preview" ~/Desktop/screenshot.png` to open the image in Preview.

Comment: Of course, you could make this a shell script, make it executable with `chmod +x remove_background.sh` and run it with `./remove_background.sh`. (`remove_background` is just a sample name for the script)

Comment: @Mazzy I made a script in shortcuts to remove the background of a fixed file location (which i save and replace with another program) and save the removed background picture also to a fixed location. So I have only the script: shortcuts run RemoveBG

Answer (score 1):

I use [GraphicsMagick](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/283445/119271) (FOSS) to run a one-liner to remove the background from images. Below is the command I use to make the background transparent.

```
gm convert infile.png -fuzz 5% -transparent "#ffffff" outfile.png
```

What this is doing is taking the `infile.png` file and with the `convert` command, [making transparent the color defined in hex](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/GraphicsMagick.html#details-transparent); in this case white (#ffffff)

You may have to adjust the “fuzz” factor depending on how precise you need it.  `-fuzz` gives you some wiggle room by allowing close to the color you specified to be selected.